# Android Studio Firebase Realtime adding nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently working with Android Studio(Java) and Firebase Realtime. I am having an issue, I want to add another node called "Goals" into my Meetings, unfortunately, it keeps adding it into the database but not creating a "Goals" node like this:

[image: Like this]

Is there any way to do this instead:

[image]

Or can I create a Goals node but have it connect to the Meetings unique key?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code that you currently have that generates the unwanted result. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond with @.